# sms filter using broadcast receiver

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to hide some messages from inbox,and turned and that's placed in a new database....my code as SmsFilter.java follows

```
public class SmsFilter extends BroadcastReceiver{

SQLiteDatabase mydb,messagedb;
String number;
ArrayList<String> private_num = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

//private named database contains numbers those which i wish to hide

    mydb=context.openOrCreateDatabase("private", 0,null);
    mydb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tab1(num INT(13))");


    Cursor  cur=mydb.rawQuery("select * from tab1", null);
    while(cur.moveToNext())
    {
        number=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("num"));

        private_num.add(number);
    }

    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        if (extras != null) {

            Object[] pdus = (Object[])extras.get("pdus");

            if (pdus.length < 1) return;

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String sender = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {

                SmsMessage message = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);

                if (sender == null) sender = message.getOriginatingAddress();

                String text = message.getMessageBody();
                if (text != null) sb.append(text);

            }
            for(int i=0;i<private_num.size();i++)
            {
                if (sender.equals(private_num.get(i))) {

             // create a new database and insert messages

                    messagedb=context.openOrCreateDatabase("message",0, null);
                    messagedb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tab2(sender INT(13),body varchar)");
                    mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO tab2 VALUES('"+sender+"','"+sb+"')");

                    abortBroadcast();
                }

            }

        }
    }

}}
```

also manifest as follows

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>

<receiver android:name=".SmsFilter">

            <intent-filter android:priority="1">

                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />

            </intent-filter>

    </receiver>
```

But i can't hide my messages by this receiver....what's the reason?.....anyone help me...i am in trouble....

Comment: have added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>

Comment: thats already i done...check my code

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>

Comment: can you check flow is reached in onReceive likes using Toast...?

Comment: @Dipin.K.G hi, i'm having the same problem. did you fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

increase the priority to a highest possible integer..that **"intent-filter android:priority="2^32-1"**

Comment: i have checked 999 as priority but no change

Comment: don't restrict yourself to 999 because you can give the highest possible integer that is even greater than 999. Since in java integer is 32 bit wide, (2^32 -1) is the only highest integer possible. So please use it and give a try.

Comment: And please note, if you have any application that already has the highest priority for receiving messages then your application cannot abort the broadcasting of messages. Some applications such as go-ex launcher has this problem. So please uninstall those applications and try.

Comment: i am placing priority like    intent-filter android:priority="2^32-1       or     <intent-filter android:priority="2147483648">

Comment: sorry for the mistake its (2^31)-1 that is <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">

Answer (score 0):

change your code:

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsFilter">

        <intent-filter android:priority="100">

            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />

        </intent-filter>

</receiver>
```

Comment: Could you explain how this answer the original question?

Comment: I agree with beresfordt; please explain. Why should this work? How is this approach different than that given in the previous answer?